# What do "orange" and "spindle-shanked beaux" mean in this quote?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, archaicisms

While looking up the word "bye" I found this 18th century quotation.

> Our present race of spindle-shanked beaux had rather close with an
>   orange wench at the playhouse, than engage in a bye battle at
>   Tottenham Court.

Can anyone give a full translation into modern English? I understand that a bye battle is an event not in the programme.  I know where Tottenham Court is in London and I know what a wench is. But the rest is obscure to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The number of unfamiliar, archaic words collocated here makes it a challenge even to a native speaker.

In order of appearance (all definitions taken from [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com) except where otherwise indicated):

*Spindle-shanked* means ‘having long, thin legs’. It’s rather a contemptuous term to use, whereby a person’s shanks (legs) are compared in shape to a spindle.

*Beaux* is the plural of *beau*, meaning ‘a rich, fashionable young man; a dandy’.

*Close* is a verb here, meaning ‘to come close together in contact or union; to join, unite, combine, coalesce, meet in a common centre’ ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34607#eid9154668)), in this case referring to close *romantic/sexual* contact.

*Orange wench* is an old-fashioned term for a young girl who sells oranges (and other fruits, presumably) in the streets.

In other words, the whole thing means, roughly translated into 21st-century English:

> Our current race with its lanky, dolled up pretty-boys [who] would rather fiddle around with the greengrocer’s girl behind the local drive-in than get in on a backalley fight [for money] at a boxing match.

(See StoneyB’s answer for more details on the context of boxing matches)

Comment: Thank you. Two questions... a)  Does "race" refer to the state of contemporary culture? In other words is it a lament about the state of the world today? b) What would closing something as General Reference mean?

Comment: @Lembik _Race_ here is used in the sense of _human race_, so yes: it’s a good old-fashioned “Ah, youth today is worthless!” piece by an old curmudgeon. Closing a question as General Reference means that the answer to the question could have been easily found by simply looking up the relevant information (in this case, the difficult words) in a common reference work (in this case, a dictionary). The reason this gets by without being General Reference is that there are so many archaic expressions here that just looking in a dictionary wouldn’t be enough after all.

Comment: Thanks again. Here is the quote in context https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xghAAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA70&ots=T5Gp5PgeMe&dq=Our%20present%20race%20of%20spindle-shanked%20beaux%20had%20rather%20close%20with%20an%20orange%20wench%20at%20the%20playhouse%2C%20than%20engage%20in%20a%20bye%20battle%20at%20Tottenham%20Court.&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=Our%20present%20race%20of%20spindle-shanked%20beaux%20had%20rather%20close%20with%20an%20orange%20wench%20at%20the%20playhouse,%20than%20engage%20in%20a%20bye%20battle%20at%20Tottenham%20Court.&f=false .

Comment: +1 But *race* I think is meant in the older sense of *nation*, not species.

Comment: I think _orange wench_ might also be a euphemism for _prostitute_ rather than completely literal.

Comment: @Frank Do you know of any evidence for "orange wench" meaning prostitute? (I also  think it is likely.)

Comment: @Lembik Yes - there's analysis here http://aljwhite.com/?p=254 and a number of poems from the 17th-18th century including The Stage by Francis Reynardson - https://books.google.com/books?id=3goUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA19&dq=%22orange+wench%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N3vYVJy_CYe0uASR94Eg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22orange%20wench%22&f=false

Comment: in "The Sexual History of London: From Roman Londinium to the Swinging City---Lust, Vice, and Desire Across the Ages" ( http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Sexual-History-London-City-Lust/dp/0312600348 ) Catherine Arnold  lays out how and why orange girls were perceived to be prostitutes at the time. Obviously the writing of the time will be informed by these perceptions whether they are right or wrong.

Answer (score 24):

The [context](https://books.google.com/books?id=xghAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=Our+present+race+of+spindle-shanked+beaux&source=bl&ots=T5Gp5PfeN5&sig=vCTKIN0_4_32G6BzbG2h4IHFM5c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1sDXVO2VA8WigwT4v4CwAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Our%20present%20race%20of%20spindle-shanked%20beaux&f=false) of this quotation is fisticuffs, and "Tottenham Court" refers to the school where James Figg taught boxing, fencing and quarterstaff.

An 'orange wench' was a woman who sold oranges and other refreshments at a playhouse, and to 'close' with her means to engage her in conversation, probably with dishonorable intentions.

A 'spindle-shanked beau' is a fashionable gentleman with thin calves. Muscular calves were admired in the 18th century, a period when men's clothing was designed to display the lower leg.

Comment: Ah! You beat me to it by just one single second!